# Is the number of columns in align environment restricted?

Tags: horizontal-alignment, equations, align

I am using align environment to write First order conditions for Lagrangian.

This is how my code looks like:

```
\documentclass[a4paper,12pt]{article}
\usepackage{amsmath,amssymb,amsfonts,amsthm}
\usepackage{derivative} 

\begin{document}

\begin{gather}
\begin{align}
&\left[u_t\right]: &\pdv{\mathcal{L}}{u_t} = 0 &\Rightarrow \theta^t \left[ R_t^k \overline{K}_t - \gamma^\prime (u_t)\overline{K}_t P_t^i \right] = 0  \nonumber \\
&&&\Rightarrow R_t^k = \gamma^\prime\left(u_t\right) P_t^i  \\
&\left[I_t\right]: &\pdv{\mathcal{L}}{I_t} = 0 &\Rightarrow \theta^t \left[ -P_t^i + \lambda_t  \left( 1- \tilde{S} \left(\frac{I_t}{I_{t-1}} \right) + I_t \left(- \tilde{S}^\prime \left(\frac{I_t}{I_{t-1}} \right) \frac{1}{I_{t-1}} \right) \right)\right] \nonumber  \\  
&&&+ \theta^{t+1} E_t \left[ \lambda_{t+1} I_{t+1} \left( -\tilde{S}^\prime \left( \frac{I_{t+1}}{I_t} \right) \frac{I_{t+1}}{I_t^2} (-1)\right) \right] = 0 \nonumber \\
&&&\Rightarrow P_t^i = \lambda_t \left( - \tilde{S} \left( \frac{I_t}{I_{t-1}} \right) - \tilde{S}^\prime \left( \frac{I_t}{I_{t-1}} \right) \frac{I_t}{I_{t-1}} \right)
\end{align}
\end{gather}

\end{document}
```

In the sample above i have 3 columns in *align* environment. The only thin I would like to do is to align  + sign on the forth line with $ \theta^t $ on the third line. For this, I am adding the forth column by adding & on every line. However, what happens is that everything aligns on the left hand side like this:

```
\documentclass[a4paper,12pt]{article}
\usepackage{amsmath,amssymb,amsfonts,amsthm}
\usepackage{derivative}

\begin{document}

\begin{gather}
\begin{align}
&\left[u_t\right]: &\pdv{\mathcal{L}}{u_t} = 0 &\Rightarrow &\theta^t \left[ R_t^k \overline{K}_t - \gamma^\prime (u_t)\overline{K}_t P_t^i \right] = 0  \nonumber \\
&&&\Rightarrow &R_t^k = \gamma^\prime\left(u_t\right) P_t^i  \\
&\left[I_t\right]: &\pdv{\mathcal{L}}{I_t} = 0 &\Rightarrow &\theta^t \left[ -P_t^i + \lambda_t  \left( 1- \tilde{S} \left(\frac{I_t}{I_{t-1}} \right) + I_t \left(- \tilde{S}^\prime \left(\frac{I_t}{I_{t-1}} \right) \frac{1}{I_{t-1}} \right) \right)\right] \nonumber  \\  
&&&&+ \theta^{t+1} E_t \left[ \lambda_{t+1} I_{t+1} \left( -\tilde{S}^\prime \left( \frac{I_{t+1}}{I_t} \right) \frac{I_{t+1}}{I_t^2} (-1)\right) \right] = 0 \nonumber \\
&&&\Rightarrow &P_t^i = \lambda_t \left( - \tilde{S} \left( \frac{I_t}{I_{t-1}} \right) - \tilde{S}^\prime \left( \frac{I_t}{I_{t-1}} \right) \frac{I_t}{I_{t-1}} \right)
\end{align}
\end{gather}

\end{document}
```

I am really confused why does align do this. It seems to me I am doing everything well. Is a way to have + on the third align aligned with $ \theta^t $ and have all the equations centered at the same time.

I have tried all possible combinations for the last 2 hours but could not find any solution. So, would be grateful if more advanced and experienced user of *align* environment suggested his/her solution.

Update: It seems that I solved the problem by removing & from the beginning of each line, but the it looks still not elegant. It seems align environment aligns each part of the line to the left with each column. Is there a way to align in the center of each column?

```
\documentclass[a4paper,12pt]{article}
\usepackage{amsmath,amssymb,amsfonts,amsthm}
\usepackage{derivative} 



\begin{document}


\begin{gather}
\begin{align}
\left[u_t\right]: &\pdv{\mathcal{L}}{u_t} = 0 &\Rightarrow &\theta^t \left[ R_t^k \overline{K}_t - \gamma^\prime (u_t)\overline{K}_t P_t^i \right] = 0  \nonumber \\
&&\Rightarrow &R_t^k = \gamma^\prime\left(u_t\right) P_t^i  \\
\left[I_t\right]: &\pdv{\mathcal{L}}{I_t} = 0 &\Rightarrow &\theta^t \left[ -P_t^i + \lambda_t  \left( 1- \tilde{S} \left(\frac{I_t}{I_{t-1}} \right) + I_t \left(- \tilde{S}^\prime \left(\frac{I_t}{I_{t-1}} \right) \frac{1}{I_{t-1}} \right) \right)\right] \nonumber  \\  
&&&+ \theta^{t+1} E_t \left[ \lambda_{t+1} I_{t+1} \left( -\tilde{S}^\prime \left( \frac{I_{t+1}}{I_t} \right) \frac{I_{t+1}}{I_t^2} (-1)\right) \right] = 0 \nonumber \\
&&\Rightarrow &P_t^i = \lambda_t \left( - \tilde{S} \left( \frac{I_t}{I_{t-1}} \right) - \tilde{S}^\prime \left( \frac{I_t}{I_{t-1}} \right) \frac{I_t}{I_{t-1}} \right)
\end{align}
\end{gather}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: align (why are you wrapping it in gather?) is designed to work with pairs of columns aligning left and right so two equations on the same line use `a&=b & c&=d\\ `  so four columns.

Comment: I am using gather in order to have each part of the line in the center of the corresponding column. or at least, thinking to be using for this purpose.

Comment: I get undefined control sequence `\pdv` on your example

Comment: I am editing the code now. \pdv comes from \usepackage{derivative}

Comment: Try it now. It should work now.

Comment: gather isn't doing any centering here, it just centers the block as a whole, but align does that anyway

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you need only one column of `&` alignment points.

[image]

Observe the use of explicit parenthesis-sizing instructions and of `\mleft` and `\mright` in lieu of `\left` and `\right`; they serve mainly to conserve on horizontal whitespace.

```
\documentclass[a4paper,12pt]{article}
\usepackage{amsmath,mleftright,derivative}

\begin{document}
\begin{align}
[u_t]: \quad \pdv{\mathcal{L}}{u_t} = 0 
&\Rightarrow \theta^t \bigl[ R_t^k \overline{K}_t - 
 \gamma'(u_t)\overline{K}_t P_t^i \, \bigr] = 0  \nonumber \\
&\Rightarrow R_t^k = \gamma'(u_t) P_t^i  \\
[I_t]: \quad \pdv{\mathcal{L}}{I_t} = 0 
&\Rightarrow \theta^t \biggl\{ -P_t^i + \lambda_t  
 \mleft[ 1- \tilde{S} \Bigl(\frac{I_t}{I_{t-1}} \Bigr) + I_t 
 \mleft(- \tilde{S}'\Bigl(\frac{I_t}{I_{t-1}} \Bigr) \frac{1}{I_{t-1}} \mright) 
 \mright]\biggr\} \nonumber  \\  
&\qquad + \theta^{t+1} E_t \biggl[ \lambda_{t+1} I_{t+1} 
 \mleft( -\tilde{S}'\Bigl( \frac{I_{t+1}}{I_t} \Bigr) 
 \frac{I_{t+1}}{I_t^2} (-1)\mright) \biggr] = 0 \nonumber \\
&\Rightarrow P_t^i = \lambda_t \mleft[ - \tilde{S} 
 \Bigl( \frac{I_t}{I_{t-1}} \Bigr) - 
 \tilde{S}'\Bigl( \frac{I_t}{I_{t-1}} \Bigr) \frac{I_t}{I_{t-1}} \mright]
\end{align}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Thanks. Is it possible to center second and forth line after \Rightarrow? That would be the most elegant and cool-looking.

Comment: And why do u use sometimes \Bigg[ and sometimes \mright[? Is not it better to be consistent and use one of them all the time?

Comment: @G.T. - To be completely open, I began by replacing `\left` and `\right` with `\mleft` and `\mright`. I then downsized several pairs of parentheses by using `\Bigl` and `\Bigr`. I suppose the task of making everything consistent -- by replacing the remaining instances of `\mleft` and `\mright` with `\biggl` and `\biggr`, right? -- is left as an exercise for the reader. :-) If one were to center the 2nd line, I suspect it would simply "disappear", visually speaking. BTW, for me to judge what's cool, I should have some understanding of the *meaning* of these equations -- which I sadly do not.